# How to use dynamic dates in a Search-Mailbox query?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have this PowerShell snippet to delete e-mail between 2 dates:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity <username> -SearchQuery '(Received:09/20/2012..10/12/2012)' -deletecontent
```

I want to make it dynamic so that it deletes e-mail older than 6 months. How can I calculate the date of 6 months ago to use in this snippet?

I have tried:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)
Search-Mailbox -Identity Sales -SearchQuery '(Received:<$date)' -DeleteContent
```

but it shows the error message:

> The property keyword isn't supported.

Comment: This is just basic date manipulation and strings. Using `Get-Date` and its method `.AddDays()` would be the start of what you are looking for. Is there something you have tried for this that is not working?

Comment: @Matt OK, updated.

Comment: Much better. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

`$date` is a `System.DateTime` object. When converted to a string it will show both date and time information which is dependent on your regional settings. This is what mine looks like:

```
PS M:\Scripts> $date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)

PS M:\Scripts> $date

Sunday, March 27, 2016 9:30:20 AM

PS M:\Scripts> "$date"
03/27/2016 09:30:20
```

That last line does not meet the standards required by [KQL (Keyword Query Language)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee558911(v=office.15).aspx)

> - YYYY-MM-DD
> - YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
> - YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
> - YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssfrZ

Since you just want the date portion lets just get that.

```
(Get-Date).AddMonths(-6).ToShortDateString()
3/27/2016
```

While that does not use hyphens, in my case, it appears the syntax allows for it in your test cases. There are oodles of ways to format dates in PowerShell. Here is one that conforms to the syntax in TechNet

```
(Get-Date).AddMonths(-6).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
2016-03-27
```

Point is you have to do *something* that will satisfy your query syntax. Test some string without `-deletecontent` first or just write the string to console to see what it looks like.

For a span of time you would use one of the above suggestions and, assuming you save those string results in variables, it would look something like this:

```
-SearchQuery '(Received:$fromDate..$toDate)'
```